# Why should there be a use of perfect to make this statement grammatical?

Tags: tense, future-tense, perfect-aspect

1. In a week's time I will complete my work.
2. In a week's time I will have completed my work.

Option 2 is given as the correct answer which is future perfect tense. The first sentence is simple future tense, but why first is not true? Grammatically I do not find any error in it.

Comment: I don't think the first one is incorrect. People generally say "I will complete my work in a week's time".

Comment: @Varun I'd appreciate it if you pay attention to vague titles and edit them into something more acceptable.

Comment: The reason the perfect is considered correct there is that "in a week's time" is (usually) understood to refer to a stretch of time rather than to a point in time a week from now.

Comment: But many people use "in a week's time" to mean "a week from now" or "a week later".

Answer (score 4):

As you say, the first sentence has no grammatical error.

If that is the entire question, the test is badly designed. Perfect constructions are used to establish temporal reference relative to the discourse context. But there is no context here, so there is no evident reason to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think that ''In a week's time I will have completed my work'' is marked correct  because .....future perfect tense is used when out of two actions it is necessary that the preceeding action will be completely finished before the succeeding action starts in future.